# How to Enforce VM Role Policy in Existed Subscription But Excluding Specific Resource Group

Tags: powershell

I have been requested to enforce a Virtual Machine role policy in all the existed subscription in Azure in Terraform scripts, but at the same time, it should exclude specific types of resource group(s) in those subscriptions.

I don't have any idea how the code starts for the Microsoft Powershell and Terraform script.

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: can be terraform script also.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.